# Is "I would rather hadn't bought these pants" acceptable?

Tags: idioms, modality

I know that we say

> I would rather read a book than go out now.

How about in a case in which you went out last night but you feel regret about it? Is using "would rather " grammatically correct or common in these situations?

> "I would rather hadn't gone to party. It was terrible."

or can we can only use the word "wish" for these situations?

> "I wish I hadn't gone to the party. It was terrible."

Answer (score 2):

As Jim points out, the ordinary way of saying this employs not+infinitive, just as your first example would if it were negated:

> I would rather **not read** a book.
> I would rather **not have** gone to the party.

When you employ a finite verb in the second clause you have to supply a subject for it, even if it is the same subject as that of the main clause:

> I would rather ***he*** hadn’t gone to the party.
> I would rather ***I*** hadn’t gone to the party.
>
> She would rather ***it*** weren’t so cold.
> She would rather ***she*** weren’t so cold.

But versions with repeated subjects may sound odd to some people, particularly in conversation.

In any case, the *rather* constructions really express preference rather than regret. I suggest you avoid *rather*, and stick with *wish* in these situations.

Comment: Hi StoneyB! thanks so much for your clear and wonderful answers!

Comment: Hi StoneyB! thanks so much for your clear and wonderful answers! After I read your answers , I googled " I would rather I hadn't " and came across a article headline which says " I'd Rather I Hadn't Read That " and goes like " Last night, I read something that upset me..."  so I think it is ok to use like this..and I want to ask again in order to make sure that do  " I would rather I hadn't read that "  and " I wish I hand't read that " have completely the same meaning?

Comment: @Radiant: Yes. You understand it.

Comment: What do you think about: "*I'd rather not have bought these pants?*"

Comment: @Jim Very good point. That's just fine ... now why? - Hah! it's not the time reference at all. Or rather it *is* the time reference - it's the use of a finite verb. I will have to rewrite this.

Comment: @Radiant Jim has pointed out a better way of looking at this, and I have rewritten accordingly.

Comment: And what about the positive form? Like - "I'd rather have bought the pants". What does it mean?

Comment: I think it means "I wish I had bought the pants". Am I right? Is this usage acceptable?